# Merging two relative file URLs

Tags: java, string, url, path

Let' say I have two paths, first can look like `folder/` and second like `/anotherFolder/image.png`. I would like to merge those two paths in some automated fashion and with option for user to omit the last slash in first string and first slash in second string. So all of these

`folder/` + `/anotherFolder/image.png`

`folder` + `anotherFolder/image.png`

`folder` + `/anotherFolder/image.png`

should give me `folder/anotherFolder/image.png`

I need to merge two properties in one of my projects and I want it as dummy as possible:)So is there some trick with URL class or do I have to play around with Strings?

Comment: Please elaborate. What language are you using?

Comment: Java, my question has a Java tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29), by using the constructor which takes a File and a String as arguments, will interpret the String as a relative path to the File.

Or with [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29), you can send an URL and a String to the constructur, which will interpret the URL as a context for the String parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used `FileUtils.getFile()` from Apache Commons IO but Rolf's solution was working too.